# Problem in use WordPress Media Library image URL to upload with wc_rest_upload_image_from_url

Tags: php, woocommerce, upload, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-media

When I use `wc_rest_upload_image_from_url` and add an image url from wordpress media library e.g. `.../wp-content/uploads/2022/04...` I get following error:

woocommerce_rest_invalid_remote_image_url

Unauthorized

Error Status 400

Comment: `https://test.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/image.jpg`

Comment: Please share the real publicly accessible URL

Comment: `https://yadakmall.com/before/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/blurb_bg02.jpg`
but when I use for example `https://smartmobilestudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/leather-book-preview.png` link, it works. I also face with problem when I want send this url to woocommerce rest api when create a product

Comment: The URL is htpasswd protected - you cannot use it inside that function - ( Unauthorized Access )

Comment: but it can be opened directly when add in browser address bar

Comment: Try in an incognito window of the browser ( private window )

Comment: I try URL in Microsoft Edge private window, it can be open

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244171/discussion-between-mujuonly-and-web-design).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL provided is htpasswd protected - you cannot use it inside `wc_rest_upload_image_from_url()` function - ( Unauthorized Access ).